# Что делает это участок кода?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class CountableHashSet<E> extends HashSet<E> {
    private int count = 0;

    public CountableHashSet(){}

    public CountableHashSet(int initCap, float loadFactor) {
        super(initCap, loadFactor);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(E e) {
        count++;
        return super.add(e);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> collection) {
        count += collection.size();
        return super.addAll(collection);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }
}
CountableHashSet<String> s = new CountableHashSet<>();
s.addAll(Arrays.asList("Виталик", "Витя", "Максим"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Считает и записывает в поле класса `count` количество добавленных элементов в `HashSet`, а больше и ничего. Все остальное делает отцовский класс `HashSet` из пакета `java.util`.
Странно только, что нету декрементации при удалении.

Comment: По сути этот класс считает сколько всего было вызовов `.add()`. А узнать текущую мощность множества можно вызвав `.size()`. Видимо автора класса интересовала только статистика добавления (согласен, что подобная "неполнота" как-то отталкивает)

Comment: Собственно цель задания была в поисках недароботок и исправлении кода ( я хотел сообственно разобраться что код делает). Вы думаете что недароботка в отсутсвии декремента. Можете пожалуйста превести исправленый код. Спасибо.